# I cannot upload my chrome extension with csp in manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

In my manifest.json, I have a csp rule:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```

to use facebook and google APIs. But when I'm uploading my extention to chrome web store, an error was reported:

> An error occurred: Invalid manifest. If your manifest includes
>   comments, please remove them as our gallery does not support them yet.

When the rule of content security policy is removed, it works fine.

But this csp rule is required for my extension to work, is that a bug of webstore?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known WebStore bug, Issue [140519 Invalid Manifest error in Web Store Gallery when updating extension](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140519)

It will be fixed in the next web store release, sometime this week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it works with me:
**you must remove any [*.json]** files from the parent folder (of course ***except the manifest.json file***).
and it's better to remove any unneeded files from your application.